# How to align elements in form?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem to aligning controls in form

[image]

Buttons some higher than input or select.

**How to display them aligned in one line ?**

The code looks like below:

```html
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">

  <button class="td to-left-end" (click)="toFirstPage()"></button>
  <button class="td" (click)="toPrevPage()"></button>

  <input class="td" type="text" readonly formControlName="currentPageInfo">

  <button class="td" (click)="toNextPage()"></button>
  <button class="td" (click)="toLastPage()"></button>

  <select class="td" formControlName="pageSize">
    <option *ngFor="let item of pageSizes">{{item}}</option>
  </select>

</form>
```

Comment: You have not added text to button, Try adding that.
Eg: 

`<button class="td" (click)="toPrevPage()">Go back</button>`

Comment: I do not need text in button. Later I put into buttons background images

Comment: Then you have to set height for buttons.

Comment: Unless you are in school or trying to learn the basics, please use Bootstrap or any library with Grids and styles. 
This form will look sad even if you align content

Comment: Ali123, give me please correct example of my form? I need minimalistic code without any garbage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try `vertical-align: top` to button, input and select field. one suggestion these form control render differently in diff browsers.

In this case you need to add `appearence: none;` and set height and width for form controls.

```css
button, input, select {vertical-align: top; -webkit-appearance:none; appearance:none; height: 30px; border: 1px solid; box-sizing: border-box;}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">

  <button class="td to-left-end" (click)="toFirstPage()"></button>
  <button class="td" (click)="toPrevPage()"></button>

  <input class="td" type="text" readonly formControlName="currentPageInfo">

  <button class="td" (click)="toNextPage()"></button>
  <button class="td" (click)="toLastPage()"></button>

  <select class="td" formControlName="pageSize">
    <option *ngFor="let item of pageSizes">{{item}}</option>
  </select>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to support old IE browsers, I would recommend `flexbox`. It is responsive by default and horizontal and vertical alignment is very easy.

```css
form {
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around; /* Spread white space equally between and around items */
  align-items: center; /* Vertical alignment */
}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <button class="td to-left-end" (click)="toFirstPage()"></button>
  <button class="td" (click)="toPrevPage()"></button>
  <input class="td" type="text" readonly formControlName="currentPageInfo">
  <button class="td" (click)="toNextPage()"></button>
  <button class="td" (click)="toLastPage()"></button>
  <select class="td" formControlName="pageSize">
    <option *ngFor="let item of pageSizes">{{item}}</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

To position your buttons use "grid" that is built-in with CSS. Add "id" to each button item you want to control. Then use CSS padding and margin to get the detail adjustments of button position in place.

Answer (score 0):

Add CSS:

```
button{
height: 24px;
padding-top: 12px;
}
```